# Partially transparent (opacity) HTML5 Canvas drawings

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparency, opacity

Is it possible to create partially transparent elements on the fly in canvas? Currently I'm setting the whole canvas element's opacity in CSS, but I want to some elements to be more visible then others.

Nothing I've found so far indicates that this is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use `rgba(r, g, b, a)` (where `a` is your alpha transparency from 0 (completely transparent) to 1 (completely opaque):

```
myContext.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
```

Examples:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/4_4_canvas_rgba.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_graphics_with_canvas